# Applying Dark mode is triggering the build method of StatefulWidget a couple of time

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to apply Dark theme to the application, when I turn on and off the Switch for the dark theme I can see the build method is called a couple of times.

1. why is that?
2. is this normal behavior of flutter?
3. will this cause any performance issue?

Note: I have added a print statement in the build method to find out how many times the build method is called out.

Is there a change I should do in my code to correct this behavior?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("MyApp");
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChanger>(
      create: (_) => ThemeChanger(ThemeData.dark()),
      child: new MaterialAppWithTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class MaterialAppWithTheme extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("MaterialAppWithTheme");
    final theme = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context);

    return MaterialApp(
      home: SettingScreen(),
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
    );
  }
}

class SettingScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static final routeName = "./SettingScreen";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("SettingScreen");
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          "Settings",
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: themeData.primaryColor,
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: const Text(
                    "User Settings",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                DarkThemeOption(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DarkThemeOption extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DarkThemeOptionState createState() => _DarkThemeOptionState();
}

class _DarkThemeOptionState extends State<DarkThemeOption> {
  var enableDarkTheme = false;
  var themeProvider;
  ThemeData themeData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print("_DarkThemeOptionState init");
    themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeChanger>(context, listen: false);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("_DarkThemeOptionState");
    themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 22, bottom: 10),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text(
            "Enable Dark Theme",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          Switch(
              activeColor: themeData.accentColor,
              value: enableDarkTheme,
              onChanged: (value) async {
                // final status = await authProvider.updateThemeSetting(value);
                setState(() {
                  enableDarkTheme = value;
                  if (!enableDarkTheme) {
                    themeProvider.setTheme(ThemeData.light());
                  } else {
                    themeProvider.setTheme(ThemeData.dark());
                  }
                });
              }),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ThemeChanger with ChangeNotifier {
  ThemeData _themeData;

  ThemeChanger(this._themeData);

  getTheme() => _themeData;
  setTheme(ThemeData theme) {
    _themeData = theme;

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

From the logs, I can see each time I turn on and off the dark mode switch I see the setting screen and `_DarkThemeOptionState` being called more than 5 times.

```
I/flutter ( 1176): MaterialAppWithTheme
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): MaterialAppWithTheme
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): MaterialAppWithTheme
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
I/flutter ( 1176): SettingScreen
I/flutter ( 1176): _DarkThemeOptionState
```

[Light Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XLyp.png)

[Dark Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVqnQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is normal, because when changing the theme, localizations, etc., it must re-render the view, therefore the compilation method is called again